# Get the table name from the model in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How do I get the table name for a model in Hibernate?

Apparently there used to be a `getTableName()` method in [`ClassMetadata`](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html), but it's been removed.

There's a [`getClassMapping(String entityName)`](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#getClassMapping(java.lang.String)) method in [`Configuration`](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html), but I don't know how I can (or if I should) use Configuration from within my DAO implementation.

My DAO implementation is a subclass of [HibernateGeneralGenericDao](https://source.sakaiproject.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/generic-dao/site/apidocs/org/sakaiproject/genericdao/hibernate/HibernateGeneralGenericDao.html).

**UPDATE:** It turns out I can do what I'm trying to do without the table name. However, I will keep the question open (and try the answers as they come) for the sake of reference.

Answer (score 37):

It's a bit weird but it works:

```
ClassMetadata hibernateMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(pClassName);

if (hibernateMetadata == null)
{
    return;
}

if (hibernateMetadata instanceof AbstractEntityPersister)
{
     AbstractEntityPersister persister = (AbstractEntityPersister) hibernateMetadata;
     String tableName = persister.getTableName();
     String[] columnNames = persister.getKeyColumnNames();
}
```

Comment: There is an extra parenthesis near the end of the fifth line. Someone with enough reputation should fix it. Also, see and think about https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251580/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-6-character-minimum-for-suggested-edits and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277184/why-is-it-necessary-for-me-to-write-6-character-if-just-one-is-missing-and-what

Comment: `getClassMetadata` is deprecated

Comment: @cdalxndr yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66802699/1069426 for an updated answer.

Answer (score 32):

If you're using the Table annotation you could do something like this:

```
Table table = Entity.class.getAnnotation(Table.class);
String tableName = table.name();
```

Comment: I'm not (and honestly, I just learned about annotations), but this is a nice idea. Thanks.

Comment: Fairly sure this only works if you set the table annotation on every entity.  Hibernate works perfectly well if you don't (it derives the name from the entity name)

Comment: this is working fine but how can I get column names?

Answer (score 4):

`classMetadata` is deprecated.

Use:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public String extractTableName(final Class<?> modelClazz) {
    final MetamodelImpl metamodel = (MetamodelImpl) entityManager.getMetamodel();
    final EntityPersister entityPersister = metamodel.entityPersister(modelClazz);
    if (entityPersister instanceof SingleTableEntityPersister) {
        return ((SingleTableEntityPersister) entityPersister).getTableName();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(modelClazz + " does not map to a single table.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this relies upon an internal Hibernate class, MetamodelImpl, which is not guaranteed to retain an entityPersister method with subsequent Hibernate releases.

Answer (score 2):

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure();    
cfg.addResource("com/struts/Entities/User.hbm.xml");
cfg.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
Mappings m=cfg.createMappings();
System.out.println(">> class: "+m.getClass(className));
System.out.println("User table name:: "+m.getClass("User").getTable().getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Configuration, you can call the GetClassMapping() method for a specific type, which would give you some mapping information for that type.

(At least, this is the case in NHibernate, but I suppose that this will be similar in Hibernate).

Comment: Yes, but how do I use Configuration? Can I just create a new instance?

Comment: Some options are to create a new instance like during initialization; keep it around as a static or singleton; or use reflection to grab it from the SessionFactory. Once you have the configuration:
  configuration.getClassMapping("foo").getTable().getName();

Answer (score 1):

or displaying a list of all columns and all entities in the GUI, I needed to load a full list of table, entity, attributes and column names, types, setters, getters and even nice labels dynamically and that's how I did it based on @Tom Redfem solution refactored with java 8 stream:

```
public void loadHibernateMetadata() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Map<String, ClassMetadata> hibernateMetadata = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();        

    hibernateMetadata.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(metadata -> metadata != null && metadata instanceof AbstractEntityPersister)
        .map(AbstractEntityPersister.class::cast)
        .forEach( persister -> createNewnParam(persister));
        ;

}
```

and then createNewParam method is:

```
private void createNewParam(AbstractEntityPersister persister) {
    try {
        Class<?> $class = Class.forName(persister.getEntityName());


        List<String> getterNameRoster = Lists.newArrayList($class.getMethods())
                .stream()
                .filter( method -> method.getName().startsWith("get") || method.getName().startsWith("is"))
                .map(getterName -> getterName.getName())
                .collect(toList())
                ;

        List<String> setterNameRoster = Lists.newArrayList($class.getMethods())
                .stream()
                .filter( method -> method.getName().startsWith("set") )
                .map(setterName -> setterName.getName())
                .collect(toList())
                ;           

        Iterable<AttributeDefinition> attrs = persister.getAttributes();
        attrs.forEach(a -> {        

            String columnName = persister.getPropertyColumnNames(a.getName())[0];
            org.hibernate.type.Type hibernateType =persister.getPropertyType(a.getName());

            Optional<String> optionalGetter = getterNameRoster.stream()
                            .filter(getterStr -> getterStr.equalsIgnoreCase( String.format("get%s", a.getName()) ) ||
                                                 getterStr.equalsIgnoreCase( String.format("is%s", a.getName())) )
                            .findFirst()                                
                            ;

            String getterName = optionalGetter.isPresent() ? optionalGetter.get() : new String("");

            Optional<String> optionalSetter = setterNameRoster.stream()
                                .filter(setterStr -> setterStr.equalsIgnoreCase( String.format("set%s", a.getName()) ))                 
                                .findFirst()                                    
                                ;
            String setterName = optionalSetter.isPresent() ? optionalSetter.get() : new String("");


            Param param = new Param(persister.getEntityName(), 
                                                        persister.getTableName().replaceAll("\"", "").toUpperCase(), 
                                                        columnName.replaceAll("\"", "").toUpperCase(),
                                                        a.getName(),
                                                        getterName, 
                                                        setterName, 
                                                        hibernateType.getName(), 
                                                        capitalizeFirstLetter(splitCamelCase(a.getName()))
                                                        );
            hibernateParamList.add(param);
            logger.debug(param.toString());
        });

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error(String.format("error occured generating the params %s" , e));
    }
}
```

and two String helper method to generate nice labels, which can be irrelevant to this post

```
private String splitCamelCase(String s) {
   return s.replaceAll(
      String.format("%s|%s|%s",
         "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])",
         "(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])",
         "(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])"
      ),
      " "
   );
}

private String capitalizeFirstLetter(String s) {
    return Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(0)) + s.substring(1);
}
```

And of course in my WebAppConfig.class I get the session factory

```
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
  LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder =
            new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
  builder.addProperties(hibernateProperties());
  builder.scanPackages(new String[] { "com....model" });
  SessionFactory sessionFactory = builder.buildSessionFactory();

  return sessionFactory;
```

}

Maybe we can optimize streams a little bit more, but for me it was quite fast and easy.

Answer (score 1):

As in Hibernate 6 the mentioned solutions did not work for me I ended up with the following implementation:

```
private String getTableName(final Class<?> cls) {
    final var sessionFactory = entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.class);
    final var metaModel = sessionFactory.getRuntimeMetamodels().getMappingMetamodel();

    return metaModel.getEntityDescriptor(cls).getMappedTableDetails().getTableName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe use [SessionFactory.getClassMetadata](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getClassMetadata(java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but ClassMetadata doesn't seem to contain any information regarding the table

Answer (score 0):

You can get every tables name in your project with this function :

```
public Set<String> getTablesName() {
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);

    Map<String, ClassMetadata> classMetadataMap = sessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata();
    for (ClassMetadata classMetadata : classMetadataMap.values()) {
        AbstractEntityPersister aep = (AbstractEntityPersister) classMetadata;
        String tableName = aep.getTableName();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(tableName) || StringUtils.containsWhitespace(tableName)) {
            continue;
        }
        names.add(tableName);
    }
    return names;
}
```

Comment: This gives error `org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getAllClassMetadata is no longer supported`

Comment: Well, it means that this method is deprecated and does not work anymore

Answer (score 0):

Since getClassMetadata method is deprecated. Try something like this.

```
   Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure();
    
    StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
    
    Metadata = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    
    String tableName=Metadata.getEntityBinding(entityName).getQualifiedTableName().toString();
```