# Get annotated hibernate tablename from POJO

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, dao

I have an entity which is declared roughly like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myUserTable")
public class User implements Serializable { ... }
```

I'm making a generic DAO class, and in doing so I'd like to retrieve the "myUserTable" name. Is there any way I can reach this name?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Easy enough using general reflection:

```
import javax.persistence.Table;

.....

Class<?> c = User.class;
Table table = c.getAnnotation(Table.class);
String tableName = table.name();
```

Comment: Hmm.... I couldn't find name() in org.hibernate.annotations.Table. Am I looking at the right table class?

Comment: No, you're looking at the Hibernate-propriety extensions to JPA. You need javax.persistence.Table.

Answer (score 8):

Similar to [Get the table name from the model in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634342/get-the-table-name-from-the-model-in-hibernate)

```
Table table = Entity.class.getAnnotation(Table.class);
String tableName = table.name();
```

Comment: and if we dont have @table annotations and complicated entity name ?