# IntelliJ/JDK 11: Cannot find symbol name() interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation

Tags: java, maven, reflection, annotations

I have this simple code:

```
String tableName = MyEntity.class.getAnnotation( javax.persistence.Table.class ).name();
```

But IntelliJ underlines the fact that the method `name()` does not exist `Cannot resolve method "name()"`.

I also get this error during the compilation:

```
Error:(29, 68) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method name()
  location: interface java.lang.annotation.Annotation
```

I saw many example codes using this method, an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320890/6643803
What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) there is no `name()` function inside the `Annotation` interfaces

You probably need to cast it:

```
Table table = MyEntity.class.getAnnotation(javax.persistence.Table.class);
String tableName = table.name();
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot Java verbosity. Thanks

Comment: @akuma8 you can just use `((Table)...).name()` if you want a more concise way