# Hibernate/Spring taking out class mapping. About reflection

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, reflection

Im trying to write an aplication with uses hibernate to write to database, however in some actions i have to use JDBC on data in tables made by HB.

JDBS is requred to give administrator ability to create SQL queries with will return statistic info about data in database like number of processed document of specified type, numbers of success/failed log in attempts or total value of products in orders.

To do that i've done an from that allows to create class that has override toString() with return nice sql query string.
All works but now im trying to make administrator live easier by hiving him an ability to choose of table/column names. And here is an problem, because they are created by hibernate. some by @column annotation other by field name.
How can i check how field mapping?
I know its all about reflections but didnt do much of that in java yet.

example

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "my_table_name" )
public class TableOFSomething implements Serializable{
   //This field isn't mapped into database and info about it is not requred.
   //In fact, info about it may cause an error.
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 7L;

   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   private String id;

   private String fieldOne;

   @Column(name="field_two")
   private String fieldTwo;

   @Column(name="renamed_just_for_fun")
   private int Number;

   //code with getters & setters
}
```

How to write methods that will have definition like

```
public <T> String tableName(Class<T> Target); //returns name of table in database
public <T> ArrayList<String> tabelFields(Class<T> Target); //returns name of fields in database
```

Comment: If you use JDBC, SQL, table and column names to query your database, why do you care about the Hibernate entities? Why don't you use the database metadata? If you really want to know about entities and their properties, use the EntityManagerFactory's meta model. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#getMetamodel%28%29

Comment: Are you sure that HQL is not good enough for your queries? It has aggregates.

Comment: Not saying that HQL is bad for this task, but tool is for person who know SQL not HQL. Sure i can tell him to click buttons or learn HQL, but isn't better to give him a tool with SQL that he know well?
@JB Nizet good point, but i'd like to try prepare those info without connecting to database, and for learning purpose ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate has API  - getClassMetadata that can explore the mapping. The API might change and is now located in another place , but i will use it and not in reflection for this.
look on this post for more details:
[Get the table name from the model in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634342/get-the-table-name-from-the-model-in-hibernate)

if you want reflection , so use this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot with hibernate way. 
However i found reflection method myself and post solution in a bit. I wonder if i covered all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import odi.beans.statistic.QueryBean;

public class ReflectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReflectionTest test=new ReflectionTest();
        System.out.println("Table name of "+QueryBean.class.getName()+" is "+test.getTableName(QueryBean.class));
        System.out.println("Column names in this table are:");
        for(String n: test.getColumnNames(QueryBean.class)){
            System.out.println("\t"+n);
        }
        System.out.println("Good bye ;)");
    }

    public <T> ArrayList<String> getColumnNames(Class<T> target) {
        ArrayList<String> ret=new ArrayList<>();
        Field[] fields = target.getDeclaredFields();
        String fieldName =null;
        for (Field f : fields) {
            //jump to next if if field is static
            if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()))
                continue;
            if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Column.class)) {
                Column a = f.getAnnotation(Column.class);
                fieldName = a.name();
            } else {
                fieldName = f.getName();
            }
            ret.add(fieldName);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public <T> String getTableName(Class<T> target){
        String ret=target.getSimpleName();
        if (target.isAnnotationPresent(Table.class))
        {
            Table t=target.getAnnotation(Table.class);
            ret=t.name();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Is it cover all possibilities?
I know now that Hibernate way would be easier, but this is also about learning of very useful reflection mechanism :)

EDIT:
Important question:
Will this work only on annotations or also on xml mapping?