# How to read all table names generated by hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm generating the `postgresql` table schema using `hibernate`:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "testdate")
    private Date thedate;
}
```

As a result I get:

```
CREATE TABLE ...
```

The table fields are all created in alphabetic order, no matter how the field order in the `@Entity` is.

When I add additional fields lateron, they are usually just appended as an extra column in the database, and not inserted in alphabetic order in between.

Question: how can I read all generated table names, in their order of insertion, from the database? And with their generated schema column names? Is that possible at all?

Sidenote: I'm maintaining the data through springs `CrudRepository` only.

Comment: You can get a `ClassMetadata` object from the `SessionFactory`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634342/get-the-table-name-from-the-model-in-hibernate. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the [`org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) you can access the [`PersistentClass`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/PersistentClass.html)es and the [`Table`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/Table.html)es.

```
public void printTables(Configuration configuration) throws MappingException {  
  Iterator classMappingIterator =   configuration.getClassMappings();

  while(classMappingIterator.hasNext()) {
    PersistentClass persistentClass = (PersistentClass)classMappingIterator.next();

    Table table = persistentClass.getTable();
    String tableName = table.getName();

    Iterator columnIterator = table.getColumnIterator();

    while(columnIterator.hasNext()){
        Column column = (Column) columnIterator.next();
        String columnName = column.getName();

        System.out.println(tableName + "." + columnName);
    }

  }
}
```

In spring you can get the `Configuration` through the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

```
 ApplicationContext appContext = ...;

 LocalSessionFactoryBean lsfb = (LocalSessionFactoryBean) appContext.getBean("&sessionFactory");
```

You must use the `&` prefix to get the factory bean. Otherwise you will get the bean that the factory creates.

You can get the `ApplicationContext` in any other spring bean by implementing `ApplicationContextAware`.

Answer (score 2):

#### As of Hibernate - 5.4.30.Final - released March 19th, 2021

the method `getAllClassMetadata()` *is no longer supported* since few years ago 
The code below works and is **not deprecated** :

```
MetamodelImplementor metaModelImpl = (MetamodelImplementor)session.getMetamodel();
Map<String, EntityPersister> entityPersisters = metaModelImpl.entityPersisters();
Collection<EntityPersister> val = entityPersisters.values();               

for (EntityPersister ep : val) {
        AbstractEntityPersister aep = (AbstractEntityPersister)ep;

        System.out.println(aep.getTableName());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aep.getIdentifierColumnNames()));
        for (String propName : aep.getPropertyNames()) {
               System.out.println(propName);
               System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aep.getPropertyColumnNames(propName)));
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

using

```
mSession.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
```

returns a Map wich you can work with.