# Adding a table name in query string dynamically in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to add table name dynamically in my query which returns `List<object[]>` as return type

I am currently appending the table name inside the query 
I don't think that's the optimal solution .Is there any other solution better than this?

```
public List<Object[]> getResult(String tableName){

try {
        Session session = currentSession();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from "+tableName);
        return query.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        closeSession();
    }

}
```

Comment: you need to show more code

Comment: The table name will be given dynamically i just want to know if there is any other better method than appending the string

Comment: you cannot pass table name as parameter, the best option will be using `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 1):

How about doing it the other way around? Instead of giving a table name and getting corresponding type, give a corresponding type and let code figure out table name.

```
public <T> List<T[]> getResult(Class<T> type){
    try {
        Session session = currentSession();
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select * from " + type.getName() + "s");
        ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList();
        for(Object o : query.list())
            result.add((T) o);
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } finally {
        closeSession();
    }
}
```

`type` is class used to represent records in the table. This example assumes that in database tables only have additional "s" in their name, so if in Java you have class `SomeObject` and corresponding table is `some_objects` you might want to do some more Java-style names to SQL-style names conversion then `type.getName() + "s"`.

Anyway - this should return you a list of elements casted to correct type, when you call `getResult(SomeObject.class);`

Comment: This will not work when `@Entity`'s name is specified.

Comment: It can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634342/get-the-table-name-from-the-model-in-hibernate

Comment: I don't have pojo for that table in that case what should i do?

Comment: You don't need it. It might be a poor choice of name, but `SomeObject` is a class name, not variable name.

Answer (score 1):

In general if you need a SQL query with variable table name you're doing something wrong.

So it would be interesting what kind of program you are writing.

I can only think of a SQL database viewer or a database dumper which would need variable table names.

Also your method seems vulnerable to a SQL injection (unless you checked the table name before calling the method).

I am personally only using prepared queries when passing any variable to a SQL query. Your query as prepared statement would look like "SELECT * FROM ?". You can try if it is supported by your database. But it should not be because such a kind of query is only needed in very rare cases.